# Please explain the working of this code?

Tags: python

```
def gSubsets(L):
    if len(L) == 0:
        print '2'
        return [[]]
    smaller = gSubsets(L[:-1]) 
    extra = L[-1:]
    print L     
    new = []
    for small in smaller:
        new.append(small+extra)
    return smaller+new
print gSubsets([1,2])
```

I am a beginner in python. I didn't get how actually the `return` at very last didn't end by getting:

```
smaller + new =[[][5]]
```

Comment: Help us help you. What is the code intended to do? What is it doing instead? My advice: create a new question, including a better explanation

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: To understand what code does, get out a piece of paper, and write down the values of all the variables. Then step through the code line by line, adding the new values.

Comment: This is actaually generating subset of a list.

Comment: you should take it step by step. this function is recursively calling itself to create subsets that get appended to a new list

Comment: I tried it ..All that confuse me is how is ?

Comment: calling recursively gives smaller [[]].but now how does "return smaller+new " is working?

Comment: smaller is a list and new is a list... it just combines them.. for instance `a_list = [1,2] b_list = [3,4]` if I do `print a_list + b_list` I would get `[1,2,3,4]`

Answer (score 2):

Break it down into pieces

```
def gSubsets(L): #recursive function
    if len(L) == 0: #when weve reached the last subset we then have to handle an empty list
        print '2'
        return [[]] #returns a list of lists for the small in smaller
    smaller = gSubsets(L[:-1]) #get subsets by recursive call for all elements in the list except the last one
    extra = L[-1:] #get the last element in the list not used in this recursive call
    print L     
    new = []
    for small in smaller: #loop through list of lists from recursive call
        new.append(small+extra) #append all combinations of the last element in the list to every other element in the same list to new
    return smaller+new #return subset with new combinations

print gSubsets([1,2])
```

this outputs

```
>>> 2
>>> [1]
>>> [1, 2]
>>> [[], [1], [2], [1, 2]]
```

by the way, in python you should use underscores in your variable and function names (its the preferred syntax) and I would work on your variable names too.. you want them to be very specific so anyone else coming by can understand what it is right away.. this is how I would rename the variables.

```
def generate_subsets_from_list(input_list):
    if len(input_list) == 0:
        # print '2'  -- not sure why you are printing 2 here?
        return [[]]
    subsets = generate_subsets_from_list(input_list[:-1]) 
    last_element = L[-1:]
    print L     
    return_list = []
    for subset in subsets:
        return_list.append(subset+last_element)
    return subsets+return_list

initial_list = [1,2]
print generate_subsets_from_list(initial_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt.

Comment: @bp_28 sure thing, does that help you understand how it works? also see my latest edit with some advise on your object/variable names